# Shared memory: location and locking strategies

Tags: linux, shared, shared-memory

I have a writer that creates a shared memory region, I'd like to ensure that readers fail to shm_open() the region until the writer is ready. My hacky way of doing this is writer will shm_open in read-only mode. Once the region is correctly constructed I chmod() the file. This is yucky, and I cannot fcntl() the file descriptor to change the permissions. Any suggestions (short of doing some awful sync in the region?)

Why is chmod() yucky? Partly because there is no glibc code (exposed that is) to tell me where the shared memory region lives (eg /dev/shm). There is some code in glibc to look through the mounts, I'd prefer not to copy it but might have no choice if noone can give me a better solution than the chmod().

Comment: This is precisely what synchronization functions are for. A process-shared mutex in the region, for example, would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using shm_open, you can certainly use mmap - this allows you to use a file in a directory of your choice (maybe it is an optimisation to place this on a ramdisc).

But to solve the locking problem, maybe you should use a mutex in the shared region, or (at a push) just flock() the file.

If you are trying to make it behave as a queue however, maybe you should just use a more queue-type IPC object instead.